# my program A PHP Error was encountered. Message: Undefined index: jenis_kelamin and Undefined index: tanggal_lahir Filename: controllers/siswa.php

Tags: php, html, continuous-integration

> Undefined index: jenis_kelamin

```
$_POST['jenis_kelamin'] = strtoupper($data['siswa']['jenis_kelamin']);
```

> ndefined index: tanggal_lahir

```
$data['siswa']['tanggal_lahir'] = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($data['siswa']['tanggal_lahir']));
```

full code

```
function update($id=1)
        {
            //set common properties
            $data['title'] = 'Update siswa';
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            //set validation properties
                $this->_set_rules();
                $data['action']=('siswa/update/'.$id);

                //run validation
                if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
                    $data['message']='';

                    $data['siswa'] = $this->siswa_model->get_by_id($id)->row_array();
                    $_POST['jenis_kelamin'] = strtoupper($data['siswa']['jenis_kelamin']);
                    $data['siswa']['tanggal_lahir'] = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($data['siswa']['tanggal_lahir']));

                    //set common properties
                    $data['title']='Update siswa';
                    $data['message']='';

                }
                else
                {
                    //save data
                    $id = $this->input->post('id');
                    $siswa=array('nama'=>$this->input->post('nama'),
                        'alamat'=>$this->input->post('alamat'),
                        'jenis_kelamin'=>$this->input->post('jenis_kelamin'),
                        'tanggal_lahir'=>date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->input->post('tanggal_lahir'))));
                    $this->siswa_model->update($id,$siswa);
                    $data['siswa'] = $this->siswa_model->get_by_id($id)->row_array;

                    //set user message;
                    $data['message']='update siswa success';
                }
                $data['link_back']= anchor('siswa/index/','Lihat Daftar Siswa',array('class'=>'back'));

                //load view
                $this->load->view('siswaEdit',$data);
        }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because stack overflow is not a free debug service.

Comment: Another question to debug your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always make use of the **`isset`** construct (*whether a value is assigned to your variable or not*) to check for the variables before assigning data.

```
if(isset($_POST['jenis_kelamin']))
{
$_POST['jenis_kelamin']= strtoupper($data['siswa']['jenis_kelamin']);
}
```

Similarly do it for your other variables.

**EDIT :**

Change your `$siswa` array like this... Add the `id` param.

```
$siswa=array('id'=>$id,'nama'=>$this->input->post('nama'),
                        'alamat'=>$this->input->post('alamat'),
                        'jenis_kelamin'=>$this->input->post('jenis_kelamin'),
                        'tanggal_lahir'=>date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->input->post('tanggal_lahir'))));
```

Comment: in view Undefined index: nama. line error code <td><input type="text" name="nama" class="text" value="<?php echo set_value('nama')? set_value('nama'):$siswa['nama'];?>"/> how solve that error?